# Jquery Loop through form and create associative array

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to loop through an un-ordered list with form fields in each.
When I try to append it to formdata and process it through PHP it just returns

```
team: "[object Object],[object Object]"
```

JS is here:

```
var arr = [];
$( '#team_list li' ).each(function(idx, li) {
    $team_name = $( li ).find('input[name="team_name"]').val();
    $team_role = $( li ).find('input[name="team_role"]').val();
    $team_citizen = $( li ).find('#country').val();
    $team_status = $( li ).find('#id_team_status').val();
    arr.push({ name: $team_name, role: $team_role, citizen: $team_citizen, status: $team_status, });
});

fd.append('team', arr );
```

Comment: If you just want to display the array then try `fd.append('team:', JSON.stringify(arr) );` otherwise you need elements to pass the values into. Say you have a div to display `$team_name` you would need to do something like this: `<div class="team-name">'+arr.name+'</div>`

Comment: Side note; just going off of your logic, it looks like your html is repeating the `country` and `id_team_status` ids.  Ids are expected to be unique per document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to [`FormData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) needs to be a string or a file; anything that is not one of these is converted to a string (see the manual). So what you are seeing is the string representation of `arr`. What you need to do is to JSON encode `arr` (using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter)) i.e.

```
fd.append('team', JSON.stringify(arr));
```

And then in your PHP code you can write

```
$teams = json_decode($_POST['team']);
```